# Why doesn't the function return a response, even if I'm sure it does? (Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I am programming a log in page for my website using flask, and this is the script of the page:

```
@app.route("/login/", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def log_in():
    if request.method == "POST":
        attempted_username = request.form.get('username')
        attempted_password = request.form.get('password')
        if attempted_username == 'username':
            if attempted_password == 'password':
                return render_template('logged_in.html')
    else:
        return render_template('log_in.html')
```

Getting to the page is no problem, but as soon as I submit anything, whether it is valid or or invalid, I get this error:

> ValueError: View function did not return a response

I know the error, it means that the function is not returning anything the browser can display, but I don't know where the hole is. I even tried to put an `else` statement after every `if` statement, which didn't work either. I tried to put responses anywhere I could.

Why this function is not returning any response, or why the error is displayed?

**Update:**

I just ran the `__init__.py` file, in which the function is situated manually (it is usually automatically trough an apache server), and he showed me:

> RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, inside `POST` many else if, so just remove last `else`

```
if request.method == "POST":
    attempted_username = request.form.get('username')
    attempted_password = request.form.get('password')
    if attempted_username == 'username':
        if attempted_password == 'password':
            return render_template('logged_in.html')
# <--- end remove else
return render_template('log_in.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MisterMM23 i edit the answer, replace `form['username']` to `form.get` method, try it

Comment: It still dowsn't work

Comment: new error? i test this code on my local machine and it's work

Comment: It's still the same error, but if it works for you I assume it has to do with some other function or script.

Comment: can you show your full code, did you corrected it ?